# Is there a way to block all keys except for CAPS with pyhook

Tags: python, pyhook

I am trying to block all keys on the keyboard except for the caps locks key using pyHook.  Below is code that blocks only the a and A key, I am looking to do the opposite.  What do I need to do to reverse this?

I have tried to put all keys on keyboard beside caps but that seems like the wrong way to approach it

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
  # block only the letter A, lower and uppercase
  return (event.Ascii not in (ord('a'), ord('A')))

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the function returns `True` the event is not blocked.

```
import string
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    return event.Ascii in string.ascii_uppercase
```

Or perhaps `return.Ascii in map(ord, string.ascii_uppercase)`.

Comment: This seems to work extremely well, except for the fact that its not detecting that as an ascii key.  Looks like CAPS is not designated in Ascii so I do not know how I will go about getting this information.

Answer (score 0):

As caps lock itself is not printable, it is not reflected in the Ascii-Attribute of your event.

But there is other attributes - namely the KeyID:

http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/

Use this to look for caps lock, according to this table:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes